# NSNotification not fired within NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm trying to convert a part of one of my Obj-C class to be able to run also on iWatch and for that, I've to use NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest: instead of NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:
It seems to have no problem around this (meaning the XML is correctly loaded & interpreted) but inside my original code, I triggered several NSNotification for the main program to achieve some visible modification.

It seems that inside the NSURLSession completionHandler, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the original code :

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *answer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:result];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_START_UPDATING object:nil userInfo:nil];
    /* DO SOME STUFF THERE */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_UPDATING_COMPLETE object:nil userInfo:answer];
}];
```

Now the fixed version looks like this :

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *subDataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *answer = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:result];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_START_UPDATING object:nil userInfo:nil];
    /* DO SOME STUFF THERE */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_UPDATING_COMPLETE object:nil userInfo:answer];
}];
[subDataTask resume];
```

What is crazy is that none of the both notifications are sent/received using the second method, where it works fine in the first version.

As well, I have a timer call in another same situation, called like this :

```
if (autoRefresh)
    refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(refreshInformationTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And here again, it works using NSURLConnection but not inside NSURLSessionDataTask...

Can you help me on this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In **any** case you should handle the `error` parameter before creating the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I'll take care of it too, but in fact it is not the solution of my main problem : why NSNotification and NSTimer doesn't fire inside the completionHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce, this test works fine. Can you try it?

```
- (void)test07
{
    static NSString * NotificationName = @"zekgnzerlkbnz";

    // Set an expectation that will be fullfill when we receive the notification
    XCTestExpectation * ex = [self expectationWithDescription:@"download ok"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NotificationName
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
                                                      [ex fulfill];
                                                  }];
    // Prep a download request
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Fire download. Send notif upon completion
    NSURLSessionDataTask *subDataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NotificationName object:nil userInfo:nil];

    }];
    [subDataTask resume];

    // Wait for 10 second or for exp to be fullfilled
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10
                                 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                     XCTAssert(error == nil);
                                 }];
}
```